# How to change or influence the block id and class of a view block

Tags: views

I have a view with 2 blocks. One was cloned from the other.
I changed the machine readable name of both of the blocks (`block_events_upcoming` and `block_events_upcoming_ical`), but in the html i get as id and classes the beautys you see below.

```
<div id="block-views-d7410a6d5618e2d319a0eaab549b0ff2"
     class="block block--views 
            contextual-links-region
            block--views-d7410a6d5618e2d319a0eaab549b0ff2">
```

Is there a way to change the ids and classes of the block. The css-class option in advanced settings only changes the css class in the block_content div not the top block-div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML ID is generated by concatenating block-view_name-block_name and
it seems there's a length limit of 32 characters. My block exceeded that limit.
So for me the solution was to shorten the block-machine-name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to give your blocks an id through the 'advanced' fieldset of your view? on the 'other' list of settings. That might do the trick.